# High Disk Write on server

Tags: performance, iis

I have 2 identical servers and currently I am monitoring both of them by setting up performance counters.

- IIS 6 with .NET Framework 2

I am noticing that one server has high disk writes of ~3300 Writes/Sec and the other server has ~199 Writes/Sec

Anyone encountered the same problem?

What may cause high disk writes?

These servers are load balanced (50%-50%)

Thanks

Comment: Identical in what? OS, OS version, Installed software, hardware they are using the same, running the same "software" -> webpage?

Comment: Maybe some info on what kind of "work" they do could give pointers. What type of (guess) webapplication do they serve

Comment: They are both idetical in terms of hardware & software.
What can cause high disk writes?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things can cause high disk activity.

- Swapping
- There's lots of stuff being written to disk
- You left ODBC tracing on (oops!)
- ...

Sounds like you're already using Performance Monitor; add some more counters to watch per process rather than systemwide:

- Process | IO Writes / sec
- Process | IO Written Bytes / sec
- Process | Page File Writes / sec

I'm not sure about the Page File Writes per second (this is from memory) but there should be something like that in there. You should be able to isolate the high activity to a process and that should help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issue can cause high disk writes, one of them is paging.
is one of these server under high memory load